# How secure are the app settings on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, configuration

It appears that each app has access to its own config settings, which could be kept after app be shutdown. I am wondering whether one app's config setting could be accessed from other app.

Should I save sensitive data like password to the app config?

Is there some better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Keychain is where passwords or other sensitive information should be saved.

Comment: Just be aware that the Keychain is encrypted using Triple-DES.

Answer (score 2):

Buzz Andersen has code that will get and set Keychain passwords correctly on both the simulator and on the iPhone: [SFHFKeychainUtils](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code).